# MySQL Prepared Statement not reading from JavaFX Textfield

Tags: java, mysql

I am stuck with this for a while and I am not sure how to fix this. The problem is my SQL query does not get the input from javaFX textfield and passwordfield(I am building a login window).
If I enter the values manually rather than getting them from a textfield the program work fine, otherwise nothing happens when you press login button. The problem occurs at the following lines, of course with no error messages:

```
 preparedStatement.setString(1,txtUserName.getText());
 preparedStatement.setString(2,txtPassword.getText());
```

Here is the full code:

```
public class LoginWindow implements Initializable{

@FXML
private TextField txtUserName;
@FXML
private PasswordField txtPassword;
@FXML
private Button btnLogin;

Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

// Setting the login button.
@FXML
private void setBtnLogin(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        connection = DBUtilities.getConnection();
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM user_login_details WHERE User_Name = ? AND User_Password = ?";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,txtUserName.getText());
        preparedStatement.setString(2,txtPassword.getText());
        resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()) {
            DBUtilities.showInforMsg("Logged in:", "You have logged in!");

        } else {
            DBUtilities.showErrorMsg("Error:", "Invalid username or password");

        }

    }catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }finally {
        DBUtilities.closePreparedStatement(preparedStatement);
        DBUtilities.closeResultSet(resultSet);
        DBUtilities.closeConnection(connection);
    }
}
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    btnLogin.setOnAction(this::setBtnLogin);
}
}
```

Comment: By entering data manually rather than retreiving it from a text field I mean:
preparedStatement.setString(1,"admin");
preparedStatement.setString(2,"admin");

Comment: can you try with `txtUserName.getText().trim()` and `txtPassword.getText().trim()` if it works?

Comment: I have tried it and it does not work. Thanks for response. Any other ideas what may be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much. I simply did not gave any ID to the passwordfield.

Comment: That means you forgot to bind the password field to the FXML document, that makes my answer a working solution. Vote my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug by first trying to print the string from your input fields:

```
 String username = txtUserName.getText();
 String password = txtPassword.getText();

 System.out.println("User name = " + username);
 System.out.println("Password = " + password);

 preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
 preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
```

If the username and password are null then make sure, those fields controller are well bound to the FXML document.